# ¿Cómo sumar días a una fecha?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saludos, tengo estas 2 variables: `var numero, fecha` donde numero contiene un entero y fecha, pues una fecha `01/12/1990`. ¿Cuál sería el procedimiento a seguir en JAVASCRIPT?

Cabe destacar que las preguntas que se encuentran en *stack* obtienen las fechas con `new date()`, pero acá la fecha ya está dentro de la variable fecha. Yo probe colocando dentro de `date($("#fecha"))` y no funciono.

**NOTA: Con ajax renderizo la vista y estos datos se almacen en 2 spans, EJ** 
Gracias.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`date($("#fech"))`  no te funciona porque la sintaxis es `Date()` (mayúscula inicial) en lugar `date()` y `$("#fech")` devuelve el elemento HTML con `id="fech"` pero Date() no puede procesar un elemento HTML, se le debe pasar un valor.

Suponiendo que `fech` sea un elemento input de tipo fecha la forma de obtener el dato usando jQuery es la siguiente:

```
Date($('#fech').val())
```

```js
console.info(Date($('#fech').val()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fech" value="1990-12-01">
```

Y para sumarle días sería de la siguiente forma

```js
var fecha = new Date($('#fech').val());
var dias = 2; // Número de días a agregar
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
console.info(fecha)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fech" value="1990-12-01">
```

NOTA: Si el valor de la fecha está como contenido de un `<span>`, en lugar de `val()` usamos `text()` y el código a usar sería como el siguiente:

```js
var fecha = new Date($('#fech').text());
var dias = 2; // Número de días a agregar
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
console.info(fecha)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="fech">1990-12-01</span>
```

Comment: hola @ruben la fecha la traigo desde la bd, me llega a un span "01/01/1990" y el numerio de dias esta contenido en otro span, es decir vienen datos string, el dia lo puedo convertir con parseInt (asi lo hice)

Comment: +1000!!... excelente el desarrollo en la explicación, solo una pequeña omisión de tipo en la segunda linea "..y $("fech") " falto el # ;))...

Comment: @fwBasic Gracias :D (corregido)

Comment: @osmelg Agregué un ejemplo usando `<span>` para la fecha.

Comment: con ajax renderizo la vista, y en el caso de esos 2 datos, <span id="numero"></span> y <span id="fecha"></span

Comment: @osmelg ¿Tienes alguna duda sobre la respuesta?

Comment: no me esta retornando lo deseado, podemos ir al chat? @Rubén

Comment: @osmelg tal vez más tarde. Mientras tanto agrega un [mcve] a tu pregunta.

Comment: creo que la cuestion no es tan dificil, me retorna Date 1987-12-17T04:00:00.000Z , necesito solo 1987-12-17 para obtener la respuesta deseada @Rubén

Comment: @osmelg Una de varias formas es `JSON.stringify(fecha).substring(1,11)`

Answer (score 4):

Bueno, para sumar dias a una fecha tienes que recoger esos dias de algun lugar, en este caso lo puedes hacer de un input, luego asignas esos dias a la fecha que quieres sumar. Una vez sumados tenemos la fecha, luego solo mostramos la fecha con  un poco de formato. Es todo, listo.

```js
var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

function calcular() {
  //la fecha
  var TuFecha = new Date('01/01/2018');
  
  //dias a sumar
  var dias = parseInt(numero.value);
  
  //nueva fecha sumada
  TuFecha.setDate(TuFecha.getDate() + dias);
  //formato de salida para la fecha
  resultado.innerText = TuFecha.getDate() + '/' +
    (TuFecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + TuFecha.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="numero"/>
  <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es importante tener en cuenta la zona horaria, si lo haces mal, sumará los días pero al hacer `setDate()` es posible que el resultado no sea el esperado.

Esta es la solución que a mí me valió:

```js
//$("#iniciopermisoausencia") es mi input date inicial
    var calcfecha = new Date($("#iniciopermisoausencia").val()+"T00:00:00"); // fuerza la zona horaria  al formato yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00, si no se hace esto los dias se resta uno (explicación? tiene que ver con la zona horaria y que resta tiempo automáticamente)
    var calctiempopermiso = parseInt($('#tiempopermisoausencia').val()); //mis horas que se suman se ingresan por un input
    calcfecha.setDate(calcfecha.getDate() + calctiempopermiso); //lo mismo del pibe
    calcfecha.setMonth(calcfecha.getMonth()); //por alguna razón sumar 1 aquí no ayudaba
    var finanno = calcfecha.getFullYear();//guardo año
    var finmes = calcfecha.getMonth();//guardo mes
    var findia = calcfecha.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + calcfecha.getDate() : '' + calcfecha.getDate();//doy formato a dia para que sea de 2 dígitos "01", "05", "10", etc.

    finmes = finmes + 1; // sume + 1 por que parece que los meses inician desde "0" es decir que enero seria 0 y diciembre seria 11 (para que lo acepte el input date que tengo) 

    finmes = finmes < 10 ? '0' + finmes : '' + finmes; // el mismo tratamiento del día

    console.log(finanno+"-"+finmes+"-"+findia); //imprimo por consola la fecha ya correcta
```

Comment: Por favor es importante desde el inicio publicar solamente soluciones en la zona de respuestas, pues tu primer *respuesta* solo era un comentario mismo por el cual tu pub. había sido reportada (*aunque ya he removido mi reporte*)

Comment: @BetaM me parece correcto, también puedes editar la respuesta para hacerla más directa tú mismo.

Comment: No era factible la edición que propones @Arian pues no había una respuesta en si, sino solamente un comentario, pero como dije ya removí el reporte **por qué ahora sí es una respuesta**