# Como puedo al editar un invoice obtener en un input la fecha de una base datos y con otro input sumarle una x cantidad de meses o dias?

Tags: php

Quiero tener tres `input`, ejemplo:

```
<input type="fecha">que este input obtenga una fecha en la base de datos</input>
<input type="text">cantidad de meses o dia a agregar</input>
<input type="text"> que este me muestre la suma de los dos input anteriores en una fecha<input>
```

Gracias, si me pudieran ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido, para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, muestranos cuales son. de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Si la cantidad de días a agregar van a ser ingresados por el usuario, necesitas usar `JavaScript`. En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136409/c%C3%B3mo-sumar-d%C3%ADas-a-una-fecha) encuentras respuestas que pueden ayudarte.